# React Redux - list of items per some criteria

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I faced a problem with React Redux when I need for one page render multiple lists of items from the same API. For example, I have endpoint `/items` with GET param `/items?city=Berlin`. I need to render 5 cities lists of items on the frontpage.

Currently I have 1 action to handle API call.

Here is my **reducer.js**:

```
...
const initialState = fromJS({
  ...
  items: [],
  ...
})

export default function reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  ...
  switch (action.type) {
    case fetchItemsByCityRoutine.SUCCESS:
      return state.update('items', (items) => items.push(...action.payload.data))
  ...
```

}
}

**saga.js**:

```
function * fetchItemsByCity ({ payload: city }) {
  try {
    yield put(fetchItemsByCityRoutine.request())
    const response = yield call(apiClient.fetchItemsByCity, city)
    response.city = city

    yield put(fetchItemsByCityRoutine.success(response))
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchItemsByCityRoutine.failure(extractErrorMessage(error)))
  } finally {
    yield put(fetchItemsByCityRoutine.fulfill())
  }
}

function * watchItemsByCitySaga () {
  yield takeEvery(fetchItemsByCityRoutine.TRIGGER, fetchItemsByCity)
}
```

On the **Homepage** I render list of cities like this:

```
const renderCityListSections = () => homepageCityLists.map((city) => <ItemList key={city.cityName} {...city} />)
```

**ItemList component**:

```
class ItemList extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    const { cityName } = this.props
    this.props.fetchItemsByCityRoutine(cityName)
  }

  render () {
    const { items, title } = this.props

    return (
      items.length > 0 &&
      <Wrapper>
        <SlickSlider>
          {items.map((item) => <Item key={item.id} {...item} />)}
        </SlickSlider>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM** is that current solution makes rerender view too many times because every time I fetch new list for some city it adds to `items`, so items changes and it leads to trigger rerendering view.

I had a thought to create 5 different Actions for every city, but it's not seems to be reasonable solution.

**WHAT is the best approach to render multiple lists of cities on one page?**

---

**UPDATE**:

So I changed **reducer** to look like this:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  ...
  items: {
    Miami: [],
    Prague: [],
    Melbourne: [],
    Venice: [],
    Barcelona: [],
  },
  ...
})

export default function reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case fetchItemsByCityRoutine.SUCCESS:
      return state.updateIn(['items', action.payload.city], (list) => (
        list.concat(action.payload.data)
      ))
    ...
  }
}
```

so every array is immutable, but again it runs into too much rerendering.
[image]

---

Everybody who has such a problem I ended up with this **SOLUTION**:

In my **reducer** I decoupled every item for city like this:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  ...
  itemsForBerlin: [],
  itemsForAnotherCity: [],
  ...
})

export default function reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case fetchItemsByCityRoutine.SUCCESS:
      return state.set(`itemsFor${action.payload.city}`, action.payload.data)
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: How about storing the items in store by city? `state.items[city] = cityItems`?

Comment: @MartinKadlec you are talking about reducer, right? If so, it seems to me that result will be the same, because it updates `items` with new key=>value pair, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, reducer. On change the items map will be new but all its members besides the new city should still have the original reference if done right.

Comment: `let items = { Berlin: [1, 2, 3] };
let newItems = { ...items, Prague: [4, 5, 6] };
newItems.Berlin === items.Berlin; // true`

Comment: @MartinKadlec it seems to that I know where is a problem. My project is based on ImmutableJS, so I think there must be some method to add key/value pair to `items` array

Comment: It is called Immutable for a reason :) if you add items to an array you must get new array, otherwise it would not be immutable. Unfortunately, my knowledge about Immutable.js isn't that great as I always found it too bothersome to use O:)  - that is why I didn't use it in my example above.

Comment: Here, working example for you https://codesandbox.io/s/3vl8vwjmrq

Comment: @MartinKadlec, thanks, but a big difference is that I need to fetch all 5 cities simultaneously. That's where rerendering problems comes in

Comment: If you are getting data for all cities every time then you can't use immutability to check the sets of items are the same. You will either have to use deepEqual check or pass some version hash from server.

Comment: @MartinKadlec you're right. That's why I updated my question with the solution I've ended up. Thank you for you help!